# What is the difference between loadu_ps and set_ps when using unformatted data?

Tags: sse, simd, intrinsics, sse2

I have some data that isn't stored as structure of arrays. What is the best practice for loading the data in registers?

`__m128 _mm_set_ps (float e3, float e2, float e1, float e0)
// or
__m128 _mm_loadu_ps (float const* mem_addr)`

With `_mm_loadu_ps`, I'd copy the data in a temporary stack array, vs. copying the data as values directly. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be a tradeoff between latency and throughput, because separate stores into an array will cause [a store-forwarding stall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135766/can-modern-x86-implementations-store-forward-from-more-than-one-prior-store) when you do a vector load.  So it's high latency, but throughput could still be ok, and it doesn't compete with surrounding code for the vector shuffle execution unit. So it can be a throughput win if the surrounding code also has shuffle operations, vs. 3 shuffles to insert 3 elements into an XMM register after a scalar load of the first one.  Either way it's still a lot of total uops, and that's another throughput bottleneck.

**Most compilers like gcc and clang do a pretty good job with `_mm_set_ps ()` when optimizing with `-O3`, whether the inputs are in memory or registers.  I'd recommend it, except in some special cases**.

**The most common missed-optimization with `_mm_set` is when there's some locality between the inputs**.  e.g. don't do `_mm_set_ps(a[i+2], a[i+3], a[i+0], a[i+1]])`, because many compilers will use their regular pattern without taking advantage of the fact that 2 pairs of elements are contiguous in memory.  In that case, use (the intrinsics for) `movsd` and `movhps` to load in two 64-bit chunks.  (Not `movlps`: it merges into an existing register instead of zeroing the high elements, so it has a false dependency on the old contents while `movsd` zeros the high half.)  Or a `shufps` if some reordering is needed between or within the 64-bit chunks.

The "regular pattern" that compilers use will usually be `movss` / `insertps` from memory if compiling with SSE4, or `movss` loads and `unpcklps` shuffles to combine pairs and then another `unpcklps`, `unpcklpd`, or `movlhps` to shuffle into one register.  Or a `shufps` or `shufpd` if the compiler likes to waste code-side on immediate shuffle-control operands instead of using fixed shuffles intelligently.

See also [Agner Fog's optimization guides](http://agner.org/optimize/) for some handy tables of data-movement instructions to get a better idea of what the compiler has to work with, and how stuff performs.  Note that Haswell and later can only do 1 shuffle per clock.  Also other links in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

---

**There's no really cheap way for a compiler or human to do this, in the general case when you have 4 separate scalars that aren't contiguous in memory at all**.  Or for register inputs, where it can't optimize the way they're generated in registers in the first place to have some of them already packed together.  (e.g. for function args passed in registers to a function that can't / doesn't inline.)

Anyway, it's **not a big deal unless you have this inside an inner loop**.  In that case, *definitely worry about it* (and [check the compiler's asm output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) to see if it made a mess or could do better if you program the gather yourself with intrinsics that map to single instructions like `_mm_load_ss` / `_mm_shuffle_ps`).

If possible, rearrange your data layout to make data contiguous in at least small chunks / stripes.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info, specifically [these slides](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/).  But sometimes one part of the program needs the data one way, and the other needs another.  Choose the layout that's good for the case that needs to be faster, or that runs more often, or whatever, and suck it up and do the best you can for the other part of the program. :P  Possibly transpose / convert once to set up for multiple SIMD operations, but extra passes over data with no computation just suck up time and can hurt your computational intensity (how much ALU work you do for each time you load data into registers) more than they help.

---

And BTW, actual gather instructions (like AVX2 `vgatherdps`) are not very fast; even on Skylake it's probably not worth using a gather instruction for four 32-bit elements at known locations.  On Broadwell / Haswell, gather is definitely not worth using for this.

Comment: Wow, amazing answer! Thank you for all the links as well, lots to read and learn :)

Comment: Peter, You're a god gift!