# Understanding micro-architectural causes for longer code to execute 4x faster (AMD Zen 2 architecture)

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, amd-processor

I have the following C++17 code that I compile with VS 2019 (version 16.8.6) in x64 mode:

```cpp
struct __declspec(align(16)) Vec2f { float v[2]; };
struct __declspec(align(16)) Vec4f { float v[4]; };

static constexpr std::uint64_t N = 100'000'000ull;

const Vec2f p{};
Vec4f acc{};

// Using virtual method:
for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    acc += foo->eval(p);

// Using function pointer:
for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    acc += eval_fn(p);
```

In the first loop, `foo` is a `std::shared_ptr` and `eval()` is a virtual method:

```cpp
__declspec(noinline) virtual Vec4f eval(const Vec2f& p) const noexcept
{
    return { p.v[0], p.v[1], p.v[0], p.v[1] };
}
```

In the second loop, `eval_fn` is a pointer to the function below:

```cpp
__declspec(noinline) Vec4f eval_fn_impl(const Vec2f& p) noexcept
{
    return { p.v[0], p.v[1], p.v[0], p.v[1] };
}
```

Finally, I have two implementations of `operator+=` for `Vec4f`:

- One implemented using an explicit loop:

  ```cpp
  Vec4f& operator+=(Vec4f& lhs, const Vec4f& rhs) noexcept
  {
      for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
          lhs.v[i] += rhs.v[i];
      return lhs;
  }
  ```
- And one implemented with an SSE intrinsic:

  ```cpp
  Vec4f& operator+=(Vec4f& lhs, const Vec4f& rhs) noexcept
  {
      _mm_store_ps(lhs.v, _mm_add_ps(_mm_load_ps(lhs.v), _mm_load_ps(rhs.v)));
      return lhs;
  }
  ```

You can find the full (standalone, Windows-only) code of the test below.

Here is the generated code for the two loops, along with the runtime in milliseconds (for 100M iterations) when executed on an **AMD Threadripper 3970X** CPU (Zen 2 architecture):

- With the *SSE intrinsic* implementation of `operator+=(Vec4f&, const Vec4f&)`:

  ```
  // Using virtual method: 649 ms
  $LL4@main:
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]            // fetch vtable base pointer (rdi = foo)
    lea r8, QWORD PTR p$[rsp]           // r8 = &p
    lea rdx, QWORD PTR $T3[rsp]         // not sure what $T3 is (some kind of temporary, but why?)
    mov rcx, rdi                        // rcx = this
    call    QWORD PTR [rax]             // foo->eval(p)
    addps   xmm6, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
    sub rbp, 1
    jne SHORT $LL4@main

  // Using function pointer: 602 ms
  $LL7@main:
    lea rdx, QWORD PTR p$[rsp]          // rdx = &p
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR $T2[rsp]         // same question as above
    call    rbx                         // eval_fn(p)
    addps   xmm6, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
    sub rsi, 1
    jne SHORT $LL7@main
  ```
- With the *explicit loop* implementation of `operator+=(Vec4f&, const Vec4f&)`:

  ```
  // Using virtual method: 167 ms [3.5x to 4x FASTER!]
  $LL4@main:
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
    lea r8, QWORD PTR p$[rsp]
    lea rdx, QWORD PTR $T5[rsp]
    mov rcx, rdi
    call    QWORD PTR [rax]
    addss   xmm9, DWORD PTR [rax]
    addss   xmm8, DWORD PTR [rax+4]
    addss   xmm7, DWORD PTR [rax+8]
    addss   xmm6, DWORD PTR [rax+12]
    sub rbp, 1
    jne SHORT $LL4@main

  // Using function pointer: 600 ms
  $LL7@main:
    lea rdx, QWORD PTR p$[rsp]
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR $T4[rsp]
    call    rbx
    addps   xmm6, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
    sub rsi, 1
    jne SHORT $LL7@main
  ```

(On AMD Zen 2 arch, as far as I can tell, `addss` and `addps` instructions have a latency of 3 cycles, and up to two such instructions can be executed simultaneously.)

The case that puzzles me is when using a virtual method and an explicit loop implementation of `operator+=`:

**Why is it 3.5x to 4x faster than the other three variants?**

What are the relevant architectural effects at play here? Fewer dependencies between registers across subsequent iterations of the loop? Or some kind of bad luck regarding caching?

---

Full source code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

struct __declspec(align(16)) Vec2f
{
    float v[2];
};

struct __declspec(align(16)) Vec4f
{
    float v[4];
};

Vec4f& operator+=(Vec4f& lhs, const Vec4f& rhs) noexcept
{
#if 0
    _mm_store_ps(lhs.v, _mm_add_ps(_mm_load_ps(lhs.v), _mm_load_ps(rhs.v)));
#else
    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        lhs.v[i] += rhs.v[i];
#endif
    return lhs;
}

std::uint64_t get_timer_freq()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    return static_cast<std::uint64_t>(frequency.QuadPart);
}

std::uint64_t read_timer()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER count;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&count);
    return static_cast<std::uint64_t>(count.QuadPart);
}

struct Foo
{
    __declspec(noinline) virtual Vec4f eval(const Vec2f& p) const noexcept
    {
        return { p.v[0], p.v[1], p.v[0], p.v[1] };
    }
};

using SampleFn = Vec4f (*)(const Vec2f&);

__declspec(noinline) Vec4f eval_fn_impl(const Vec2f& p) noexcept
{
    return { p.v[0], p.v[1], p.v[0], p.v[1] };
}

__declspec(noinline) SampleFn make_eval_fn()
{
    return &eval_fn_impl;
}

int main()
{
    static constexpr std::uint64_t N = 100'000'000ull;

    const auto timer_freq = get_timer_freq();
    const Vec2f p{};
    Vec4f acc{};

    {
        const auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
        const auto start_time = read_timer();
        for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            acc += foo->eval(p);
        std::printf("foo->eval: %llu ms\n", 1000 * (read_timer() - start_time) / timer_freq);
    }

    {
        const auto eval_fn = make_eval_fn();
        const auto start_time = read_timer();
        for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            acc += eval_fn(p);
        std::printf("eval_fn: %llu ms\n", 1000 * (read_timer() - start_time) / timer_freq);
    }

    return acc.v[0] + acc.v[1] + acc.v[2] + acc.v[3] > 0.0f ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use a better calling convention like `__vectorcall` that passes / returns `__m128` in XMM regs?  (If that would even help, if `Vec4f` isn't treated the same as `__m128`).  I wonder if store-forwarding is the problem if the callee does scalar stores.  (update, that's what harold is suggesting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm testing this on an Intel Haswell processor, but the performance results are similar, and I guess the cause is also similar, but take this with a grain of salt. There are of course differences between Haswell and Zen 2, but as far as I know the effect which I'm blaming for this should apply to both of them.

The problem is: the virtual method/function-called-via-pointer/whatever it is, does 4 scalar stores, but then the main loop does a vector load of that same memory. Store-to-load forwarding can handle various cases where a value is stored and then immediately loaded, but generally not a case like this where a load depends on multiple stores (on more generally: a load that depends on a store that only partially supplies the data that the load tries to load). Hypothetically it may be possible, but it is not a feature of current micro-architectures.

As an experiment, change the code in the virtual method to use a vector store. For example:

```
__declspec(noinline) virtual Vec4f eval(const Vec2f& p) const noexcept
{
    Vec4f r;
    auto pv = _mm_load_ps(p.v);
    _mm_store_ps(r.v, _mm_shuffle_ps(pv, pv, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 0, 1, 0)));
    return r;
}
```

On my PC that brings the time back in line with the fast version, which supports the hypothesis that the problem is caused by the multiple scalar stores feeding into a vector load.

Loading 16 bytes from an 8 byte `Vec2f` is not completely legitimate, that could be worked around if necessary. With only SSE(1) it is a bit annoying, SSE3 would be nice for `_mm_loaddup_pd` (aka `movddup`).

This problem wouldn't have existed if MSVC returned the `Vec4f` result via a register instead of via an out-pointer, but I don't know how to convince it to do that, apart from changing the return type to `__m128`. `__vectorcall` also helps, but makes MSVC return the struct in *several registers* which are then recombined in the caller with extra shuffles. It's a bit of a mess and slower than either of the fast options, but still faster than the version with a store-forwarding failure.

Comment: For reference re: current uarches: [Can modern x86 implementations store-forward from more than one prior store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46135766) - apparently in-order Atom can do this, but nothing current can.  (i.e. nothing with OoO exec).

Comment: 64-bit code can assume SSE2, where a 64-bit XMM load can be done with `movsd`.  Some annoying casting with intrinsics, but doable.  (Or at least I thought it was.  I thought intrinsics were supposed to be aliasing-save, but unfortunately GCC's `_mm_load_sd( (const double*)ptr)` implementation in emmintrin.h just derefs that pointer without using a a `may_alias` typedef for double the way some other load/store intrinsics do.)

Comment: @PeterCordes and SSE(1) has `movlps` which I wanted to use initially, but the intrinsic is weird with its `__m64*` argument.. I don't think this is an important aspect of the question though

Comment: Right, but SSE1 `movlps` is a worse choice in asm because you need / want to break the false dependency on the destination register.  Unlike SSE2 `movsd` / `movq` which are pure loads that zero-extend, so the only pain is C++ source-level and wresting the compiler into submission so safely emit just that instruction.  (Intel intrinsics are pretty garbage for narrow loads/stores; they should have been `void*` with clearly-defined aliasing-safe semantics from the start :/)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes and @harold for the excellent insights. Store forwarding being defeated looks like the culprit here. I was able to eliminate the performance penalty using `__vectorcall` (or `/Gv`), or by using vector instructions to store return values from the virtual method / function.