# C++ map fast 1,2,3 integers to hardcoded chars?

Tags: c++, performance

I need to map int values 1,2,3 to chars 'C', 'M', 'A'

Whats the **fastest** way (this will be called 100s times per sec 24/7)?

a macro or an inline function and bunch of ?: operators or ifs or switch? or an array?

Comment: `int map[4] = { 0, 'C', 'M', 'A' };`

Comment: yeah you beat me to the edit! :) if you are sure - write it as an answer

Comment: 100s of times per second is not very many times per second. You have a computer that can probably do it 1000000000 times per second. Per core.

Comment: I think C64 Basic was fast enough for that.... Implement it any way you can think of. Then try. Use your favorite search engine on "premature optimisation".

Comment: there are a lot of other things go in each call. optimisation is a must in my case.

Comment: If that translation is really static like that, your lookup table can be declared constexpr as well.

Comment: Where does the numbers 1,2,3 come from?

Comment: Your compiler will optimize such trivialities. If it does not, and you have performance issue, then start profiling and optimizing.

Comment: "there are a lot of other things go in each call". If that fills up your second, then "optimisation" ... elsewhere... "is a must" .

Comment: @BoppityBop your computer can do this a billion times a second. And you say it's only doing this 100s of times a second (let's be generous and say it's 999 times). So what is the computer doing for the other 99.9999001% of the time? Maybe you should optimize that thing instead

Comment: `static_cast<char>(35+(43-11*x)*x)` (though a lookup table or switch+case is probably going to be faster)

Comment: @Artyer -- a lookup table or switch+case also doesn't hard-wire assumptions about the character encoding.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, but it says 100s times per second 24/7. So if it runs long enough you can put a price tag on the additional energy wasted on a slow computation.

Comment: @bitmask no matter how long you run it, the other part of the program uses at least a million times more energy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lookup-table seems the most obvious approach as it is also branch-free:

```
constexpr char map(std::size_t i) {
  constexpr char table[] = "0CMA";
  // if in doubt add bounds checking for i, but it will cost performance
  return table[i];
}
```

Observe that with optimisation, the lookup table [boils down](https://godbolt.org/z/snTsWb5bq) to an integer constant.

Edit: You can shave of an additional instruction if you are less lazy than me and specify the lookup table thusly:

```
  constexpr char table[] = {0, 'M', 'C', 'A'};
```

Comment: @user253751 I don't know. If in doubt one would have to benchmark. It *does* get compiled to the same number of instructions, tough. And I would argue that magic constants are less maintainable, so there is that.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal: `(char)(0x414D4300 >> (i * 8))`

Instead of 0x414D4300 you could write `(('C' << 8) | ('M' << 16) | ('A' << 24))`.

Only actual testing will tell you whether this is faster than bitmask's answer.

If this runs only 100 times per second, you're chasing a red herring, anyway. Even if you write this section in the dumbest way possible, it seems to be a million times faster than the rest of your program.

Comment: How to obfuscate your code for no benefit at all 101

Comment: If you look at the code that `bitmask` linked, you'd see the same (or very similar) constant produced by compiler.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I also see a word store and byte load instead of a bit-shift.

Comment: luckily, it sounds like [store forwarding does work in such cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135766/can-modern-x86-implementations-store-forward-from-more-than-one-prior-store), which I was concerned about. If the processor did not implement store forwarding in this scenario, the load could waste 10 to 50 clock cycles.

Comment: _"Only actual testing will tell you whether this is faster than bitmask's answer"_ - [Benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/KvV5dv8RLjl731n9P85WWUaoZMc)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well that is interesting! The memory access method is *faster* than the bitshift method. Edit: although in the bitshift method, a greater percentage of time is counted in the benchmark overhead. Perhaps both are so fast that out-of-order execution executes them in parallel with the benchmark overhead and nothing is really measured. I note that the %3 was optimized in a way that involves a bit-shift so perhaps having two shift instructions instead of one occupies the shifter unit for longer.

Comment: Yes, and I got _some_ results where the bitshifts were faster when I ran the benchmark so I can't say for sure which is faster. There's also some diff between g++ and clang++.

Answer (score 0):

You're optimizing your code prematurely. Let me prove it. Here's the naivest, slowest approach that is still reasonable:

```
#include <map>

char map(int i) {
    std::map<int, char> table;
    table[1] = 'C';
    table[2] = 'M';
    table[3] = 'A';

    return table[i];
}
```

It [generates](https://godbolt.org/z/nKGrWPvss) *hundreds* of lines of assembly instructions.

And let's time it for a million elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

char map(int i) {
    std::map<int, char> table;
    table[1] = 'C';
    table[2] = 'M';
    table[3] = 'A';

    return table[i];
}

int main() {
    int const count = 1'000'000;
    std::vector<int> elms(count);
    
    std::srand(0); // I know that rand is no good, but it's OK for this example
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        elms[i] = std::rand() % 3 + 1;
    }

    auto beg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    volatile int do_not_optimize;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        do_not_optimize = map(elms[i]);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - beg);
    std::cout << "Duration: " << duration.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the output on my computer with lots of other programs running alongside:

```
Duration: 246 ms
```

This terrible implementation under terrible conditions still meets your needs 40'650x over. I bet you have way more to worry about elsewhere in your codebase. Remember to make it right, then make it fast only if it's not already fast enough.